# grails 3.1.1 & json views

Tags: json, rest, grails

I've been playing around with Grails-3.1.1 and creating restful services but when I use them to generate from a collection and responding using templates I get the following error:

URI /api/buildings
Class java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message 
    Error rendering view: Error rendering view: Cannot write a name when a name has just been written. Write a value first!
Caused by
    Cannot write a name when a name has just been written. Write a value first!

I followed the example on the json-views github page
https://github.com/grails/grails-views

My index.gson file looks like this

```
model {
  List<Building> buildingList
}

json tmpl.building(buildingList)
```

And my _building.gson template file like this

```
model {
  Building building
}

json  g.render(building)
```

If I don't use the templates all works well but then I get too little info - I want to expand on some of the object relationships instead of just returning the id. Using a show.gson template accessing the same _building.gson file does seem to work OK. The controller in question extends from RestfulController and only implements the contructor as shown below

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class BuildingRestController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    BuildingRestController() {
        super(Building)
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong and do others have it working?

Stack trace:

```
   Line | Method
->>    8 | writeTo                 in C:\Users\Colin\code\biztool\grails-app\views\buildingRest\index.gson
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by ViewRenderException: Error rendering view: Cannot write a name when a name has just been written. Write a value first!
->>    8 | writeTo                 in C:\Users\Colin\code\biztool\grails-app\views\buildingRest\_building.gson
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by IllegalStateException: Cannot write a name when a name has just been written. Write a value first!
->>  624 | writeName               in grails.plugin.json.builder.StreamingJsonBuilder$StreamingJsonDelegate
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    563 | call                    in     ''
|    149 | process . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.JsonGrailsViewHelper
|     74 | doCall                  in grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.JsonGrailsViewHelper$_render_closure1
|    689 | cloneDelegateAndGetContent in grails.plugin.json.builder.StreamingJsonBuilder$StreamingJsonDelegate
|    681 | cloneDelegateAndGetContent in     ''
|    199 | call . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.json.builder.StreamingJsonBuilder
|     72 | render                  in grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.JsonGrailsViewHelper
|     58 | render . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|      8 | run                     in _info_app_name__buildingRest__building_gson
|     32 | doWrite . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewTemplate
|     30 | writeTo                 in grails.views.AbstractWritableScript
|    280 | render . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.JsonGrailsViewHelper
|     30 | invokeMethod            in grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.TemplateRenderer
|      8 | run . . . . . . . . . . in _info_app_name__buildingRest_index_gson
|     32 | doWrite                 in grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewTemplate
|     30 | writeTo . . . . . . . . in grails.views.AbstractWritableScript
|     64 | renderMergedOutputModel in grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView
|     94 | render . . . . . . . .  in grails.views.mvc.renderer.DefaultViewRenderer
|    188 | internalRespond         in grails.artefact.controller.RestResponder$Trait$Helper
|     62 | respond . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     64 | index                   in grails.rest.RestfulController
|     96 | doInTransaction . . . . in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|     93 | execute                 in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     80 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter
|     53 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    143 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter                in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     58 | doFilter . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|     35 | doFilterInternal        in CorsFilter.java
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: You seem to be passing a list to a template that's expecting a single item `tmpl.building(buildingList)`... Can you try `tmpl.building(buildingList[0])` to check if this is the issue?

Comment: I believe it should be `json(buildingList) { tmpl.building(it) }` in `index.gson`. I will play around with it little bit before confirming.

Comment: I tested with a sample app and it works as expected (they way you have in your question). Can you do a grails clean and re run? If required I can share the sample app, but it is plain simple. `grails create-domain-class Sample && grails create-restful-controller Sample && grails generate-views Sample && grails run-app` is what I used to test.